# OpenPGP C++: cmake - library not found for -lgmpxx

Tags: c++, cmake, openpgp

### Context

I am trying to use the [OpenPGP C++ library](https://github.com/calccrypto/OpenPGP) on a MacOS machine.

### Issue

I am following the instruction to build the library:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
<make test>
make install
```

I manage to run the `cmake`. When passing to the step of `make` it returns an error:

```
[...]
[ 54%] Linking CXX shared library libOpenPGP.dylib
ld: library not found for -lgmpxx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libOpenPGP.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenPGP_shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### What I tried

After reading online I found that could have been an issue of not properly run the `cmake` command.

- I re-runned the `cmake` command (deleting the build folder content first)
- I re-cloned the repository

Comment: The error message is "library not found for -lgmpxx". Why do you use **meaningless** "linker command failed with exit code 1" in the title?

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the suggestion, I am trying to better understand this error to move forward in using the library

Comment: In their [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/calccrypto/OpenPGP/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L65) there is `link_libraries (${GMP_LIBRARIES} gmpxx)`. Probably, aside from GMP library you need also install gmpxx.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did install GMP as per requirement, that's why I'm confused about the error

Comment: gmpxx is NOT a GMP. So, have you installed gmpxx?

Comment: @Tsyvarev looking on the internet is bringing me always to the GMP installation. I did try to install it with brew `brew install gmpxx` yet it did not find the package for the installation. Do you know where can I find more info about it?

Comment: Hmm, it actually seems that gmp and gmpxx are provided in the same package. The problem of line `link_libraries (${GMP_LIBRARIES} gmpxx)` is that it allows to specify path to `gmp` library (variable `GMP_LIBRARIES` contains absolute path to the library) but `gmpxx` should be in the search paths for the linker. Report the problem to the developers.